# Django File Uploads using path

Tags: python, django, file-upload, filefield

If I upload a file to my website via Ajax, and I have the path of it, is there a way I could submit this path to a Django form's built-in FileField?

Comment: Do you actually need to submit it with form or save it into a model? In second case `obj.file.save(filename, File(open(path)))` works great.

Comment: @ilvar thank you for the info. I actually need to submit it with the form, but the info you provided is also useful for the future. Any thoughts on how I could do it with the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can construct a [`UploadedFile`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L16) instance from file-like object, put it into dict `{'name': temporary_uploaded_file}` and provide it to form's `files` argument. Haven't tried it myself but should be working.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by providing it to a form's file argument? So let's say I retrieve the path of the uploaded file; what is meant by providing it to the form's file argument? Thanks again.

Comment: `form = FormClass(data=request.POST, files=files_dict)`

Comment: I tried this: {'book_pics': <SimpleUploadedFile: movies.jpg (text/plain)>}, and it failed, but when I retrieve data from request.FILES (I don't want to do it this way, but for testing purposes), I get this value: <MultiValueDict: {u'book_pics': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: movies.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>, which does work. Any idea on how to create a MultiValueDict?

Comment: See my full post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562294/django-filefield-not-validating-with-a-simpleuploadedfile-object